How can I modify my code to be able to sort the cards by their stock and price before displaying them on the page?
I'm developing a React application with TypeScript that displays cards for a store. I'm fetching the data for these cards from one API and I also need to retrieve additional information such as stock and price for each card from another API. My problem lies in implementing functionality that allows the user to sort the cards by their stock and price before displaying them on the page. However, since the stock and price information is asynchronously obtained after the cards are rendered (its Card.tsx where I connect the results with the data from my store, stock and price), I'm unable to sort them correctly.
I'm thinking on 2 possible solutions by now:

Loading the cards before showing them on something like an Array to be able to sort them before showing.
Finding a way to sort the cards after them being loaded.
I havent been able to find a way of doing neither of them
I had the same problem before applying a "in stock" filter, but I made it work by doing a completly different search-stock.tsx because I could not make it work
This is the code of search.tsx

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../components/AuthContext";
import Cart from "../components/cart";
import Card from "../components/card";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Search = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const query = new URLSearchParams(search).get("query");
  const { user, fetchLatestUserDetails } = useAuth();
  const [noResults, setNoResults] = useState(false); // New state to track "no results" condition
  const [filterInStock, setFilterInStock] = useState(true);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);
  const pageSize = 10; // New constant to define the number of items per page

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLatestUserDetails().catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  const applyFilters = () => {
    const basePath = filterInStock ? "/stock/search" : "/search";
    const searchQuery = query ? `?query=${query}` : "";
    navigate(`${basePath}${searchQuery}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?unique=prints&include_multilingual=true&q=${query}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.code === "not_found") {
        // Check if the response indicates no results
        setNoResults(true); // Set noResults to true if no results were found
        setResults([]); // Ensure results is empty
      } else {
        // delete all data that has lang different from "en" or "es"
        data.data = data.data.filter(
          (card: { lang: string }) => card.lang === "en" || card.lang === "es"
        );
        console.log(data.data.length);
        setTotalPages(Math.ceil(data.data.length / pageSize)); // Calculate total pages
        //if data.data.length is 0, set noResults to true
        if (data.data.length === 0) {
          setNoResults(true);
          setResults([]);
        } else {
          setResults(data.data); // Set the results if found
          setNoResults(false); // Reset noResults to false
        }
      }
    };

    if (query) {
      fetchData().catch(console.error);
    }
  }, [query, currentPage]);

  const goToNextPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage((prev) => (prev < totalPages ? prev + 1 : prev));
  };

  const goToPrevPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage((prev) => (prev > 1 ? prev - 1 : prev));
  };

  return (
    <div className="searchpage">
      <div className="filters">
        <h1>Filtros</h1>
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="stockCheckbox"
            checked={filterInStock}
            onChange={(e) => setFilterInStock(e.target.checked)}
          />
          <label htmlFor="stockCheckbox">En Stock</label>
        </div>
        {/* Add Apply Filters Button */}
        <button onClick={applyFilters}>Aplicar Filtros</button>
      </div>
      <div className="search-content">
        {noResults ? (
          <h3>No se encontraron resultados para: {query}</h3>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h3>Resultados de busqueda para: {query}</h3>
            <div className="order-buttons">
              <div>
                <button onClick={goToPrevPage}>Anterior</button>
                <span>{currentPage}</span>
                <button onClick={goToNextPage}>Siguiente</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
              {results
                .slice((currentPage - 1) * pageSize, currentPage * pageSize)
                .map(
                  (
                    // its posible that some properties return null, so you can use the optional chaining operator to avoid errors
                    card: {
                      id: string | null;
                      name: string | null;
                      mana_cost: string | null;
                      colors: Array<any> | null;
                      set_name: string | null;
                      lang: string | null;
                    },
                    index: number
                  ) => (
                    // style list so it doesn't have bullets
                    <li key={index} style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
                      {card &&
                        card.id &&
                        card.name &&
                        card.set_name &&
                        card.lang && (
                          <Card
                            id={card.id}
                            name={card.name}
                            set_name={card.set_name}
                            lang={card.lang}
                          />
                        )}
                    </li>
                  )
                )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        {user ? (
          <Cart items={user.cart} userConnected={true} />
        ) : (
          <Cart items={null} userConnected={false} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;


As said before, I have tried doing my 2 possible solutions but cant get to make them work.
I dont know if there is a better way of doing this

some ideas to explore:

use local storage, like this article describes
load the data into an in-memory SQLite database--see SQLite Client for Node.js Apps

